# How to handle QRY^Q02 with ReceivingApplication in HAPI?

Tags: java, hl7, hapi, hl7-v2

I'm developing an application which interacts with Chemistry Analyzers and I need to work with the QRY^Q02 and DSR^Q03 messages.

The communication schema is as follows:

```
Analyzer                            Soft

                 QRY^Q02
   |--------------------------------->|
                 QCK^Q02
   |<---------------------------------|

                 DSR^Q03
   |<---------------------------------|
                 ACK^Q03
   |--------------------------------->|
```

I've implemented a ReceivingApplication to handle the incoming messages and generating the responses.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to send the DSR^Q03 message after responding the QCK^Q02.

One alternative is to fire a separate thread from the "processMessage", which will send the response to the query. I think this isn't a good approach to handle the query for several reasons.

Does someone know how to send the DSR^Q03 after responding the QCK^Q02 ?

If anyone can help me, I'll really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: It probably depends on you and your analyzer,how you will handle it and how or when the analyzer is ready to accept it. Is the analyzer fast enough to accept the response immediately after, is a separate port / connection needed, can you accept further requests during preparing the response etc.

Comment: Hi @sqlab, thanks for your reply. The analyzer only uses one port, and I don't know if it is fast enough. My question is more oriented to a programming problem. Is there a way in HAPI to handle the query answering ? I mean, after replying the QCK^Q02, how can I send the DSR^Q03 message to the analyzer ?

Comment: What speaks against using .sendAndReceive(yourDSR^Q03) on the connection, where you got the Query, if it is still open? Otherwise you have to initiate a new connection.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with an Analyzer System with a 3rd party network tool to test this use-case which is good work.

And after sending the `QCK^Q02`, you can send `DSR^Q03` directly (no wait, no new thread, just do it directly). Just send one by one. The analyzer will accept the information.

I hope this can help you.